# Return exception when execute app - Android

Tags: android, exception, permissions

Running the program returns this:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions1, PID: 4474
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions1/pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions1.Lastcall}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{212efa7 4474:pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions1/u0a85} (pid=4474, uid=10085) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{212efa7 4474:pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions1/u0a85} (pid=4474, uid=10085) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
>           at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
>           at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4181)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5970)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2592)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1828)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:786)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:752)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:710)
>           at pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions1.Lastcall.onCreate(Lastcall.java:19)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>        Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:12188)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:12585)
>           at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:357)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3291)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)

Code **activity_lastcall.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Lastcall">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code **LastCall.java**:

```
package pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Lastcall extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lastcall);
        TextView oTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lc);
        String strUriCalls = "content://call_log/calls";
        Uri uriCalls=Uri.parse(strUriCalls);
        Cursor curCalls = getContentResolver().query(uriCalls ,null ,null ,null , null);
        String sInfo = "Last Call:";


        if (curCalls.moveToLast())
            sInfo += curCalls.getString(curCalls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER))+"\n" +
                    "Duration:"+curCalls.getString(curCalls.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
        oTV.setText(sInfo);

    }
}
```

Code **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions1">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Lastcall">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I need to get the last call made, and write the number and name in the textview.

Answer (score 0):

add this as well to your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
```

You need to request that in runtime like below. This code should be executed before u do any call permission related task.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)) {

    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_READ_CALL_LOG);
    }
}
```

This is for read call log permission and do this for write call log permission as well if needed.

Comment: I try import ContextCompat and ActivityCompat but library don't exist

Comment: @user48571 can u change your activity to AppCompatActivity ?
 you need to change as  " public class Lastcall extends AppCompatActivity "

Comment: if change this name extend " AppCompatActivity" need create new project or not

Comment: No you don't need new project. try it and let me know if there is any error ?

Comment: return error on @override and don't recognize super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: which sdk vesrion u use as compiled sdk

Comment: Then u can add it as AppCompatActivity without error. Please check if you do something wrong. You can check support of AppCompatActivity by creating new text activity with extending that AppCompatActivity

Comment: Non-static method 'checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context. Call requires API level 23 (current min is 21): android.content.Context#checkSelfPermission

Comment: where did you call it. Please call it in oncreate() or any non-static method before do and call log related things

Comment: i call the code if if else on method oncreate(). Can edit final code Lastcall.java?

Comment: There is a something wrong in your gradle file. please try  to change minimum as API 23    due to this "Call requires API level 23 (current min is 21)". What is target sdk?

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pt.ubi.di.pdm.expermissions2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: you can expose the final code of the file Lastcall.java

Comment: ? i cannot understad. What did u mean. Is it working ?

Comment: the code you provided is to put inside the onCreate method? If so, it does not work